# A common class for Client and Server

Tags: c#, networking, socket, tcp

I have written this code to use `TcpClient` both from a client program and a server program.

Can you review this source code?

- Kindly, take a close look at **Disposable**  pattern at the bottom of the source code.

.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClientServerLib
{
    public class ClientClass : IDisposable
    {
        private string Host { get; set; }
        private int Port { get; set; }

        private bool IsConnected = false;

        public string ID { get; private set; }
        public TcpClient Tcp { get; private set; }

        private System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream stream;

        public ClientClass()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            ID = AlphaNumRandom.GenerateUpperCaseString(5, rnd);
        }

        //constructor for server program.
        public ClientClass(TcpListener listener)
        {
            Tcp = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            Host = ((IPEndPoint)Tcp.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
            Port = ((IPEndPoint)Tcp.Client.LocalEndPoint).Port;

            IsConnected = true;

            stream = Tcp.GetStream();

            ID = Read();

            Console.WriteLine("Client [{0}] is now connected.", ID);
        }

        public bool Connect()
        {
            if (IsConnected == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client [{0}] is now connected.", ID);

                IsConnected = true;

                Tcp = new TcpClient(Host, Port);

                stream = Tcp.GetStream();

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        //constructor for client.
        public ClientClass(string host, int port)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            ID = AlphaNumRandom.GenerateUpperCaseString(5, rnd);
            Host = host;
            Port = port;
        }

        public string Read()
        {
            if (IsConnected)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[Tcp.ReceiveBufferSize];//create a byte array
                int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, Tcp.ReceiveBufferSize);//read count
                string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);//convert to string
                return str.TrimEnd(new char[] {'\r', '\n'});//remove CR and LF
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Client " + ID + " is not connected!");
            }
        }

        public void Write(string str)
        {
            if (IsConnected)
            {
                str = str + Constants.CRLF;// add CR and LF
                byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
                stream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Client " + ID + " is not connected!");
            }
        }

        public void PrintID()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client ID = {0}", ID);
        }

        public void SendIdToServer()
        {
            this.Write(ID);
        }

        public bool Disconnect()
        {
            if (IsConnected)
            {
                if (Tcp != null)
                {
                    stream.Close();
                    Tcp.Close();

                    Console.WriteLine("\nClient [{0}] is now disconnected.", ID);

                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        #region dispose pattern
        // Flag: Has Dispose already been called?
        bool disposed = false;

        // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposed)
                return;

            if (disposing)
            {
                // Free any other managed objects here
                if (stream != null)
                {
                    stream.Close();
                    stream.Dispose();
                    stream = null;
                }
                if (Tcp != null)
                {
                    if (Tcp.Connected)
                    {
                        Tcp.Client.Disconnect(false);
                        Tcp.Client.Close();
                        Tcp.Client.Dispose();
                        Tcp.Client = null;

                        Tcp.GetStream().Close();
                        Tcp.Close();                        
                        Tcp = null;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Free any unmanaged objects here.
            // ...
            disposed = true;
        }

        ~ClientClass()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Down and close voter: Please explain why you down vote and/or vote for closing this question.

Comment: I am not the down voter or the close voter, but it would be better if the question contained a little more information about what the code does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things,

Your properties should be all set to `readonly` as you need to enforce your class requirements. You can make them public, but with a `private set;`. or simply `{ get; }`.

`TcpClient` is a main requirement in this class, and you didn't setup the class constructor correctly for that purpose. Because of that, you were constructing inside `Connect()`. For that, you need to setup your constructors something like this :

```
// should be private since Host and Port are Required
private ClientClass()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    ID = AlphaNumRandom.GenerateUpperCaseString(5, rnd);
}

// you can make it public or private it's optional.
private ClientClass(TcpClient tcp) : this()
{
    Tcp = tcp;

    Host = ((IPEndPoint)tcp.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();

    Port = ((IPEndPoint)tcp.Client.LocalEndPoint).Port;

    stream = tcp.GetStream();
}

//constructor for client.
public ClientClass(string host, int port) : this(new TcpClient(host, port)) { }

//constructor for server program.
public ClientClass(TcpListener listener) : this(listener.AcceptTcpClient())
{
    ID = Read();
}
```

the `Connect()` and `Disconnect()` methods are confusing, because you're returing a boolean, and also you have already `IsConnected` which you're making it true in different places, and before even initiating the `TcpClient` how come ?

You should do something like this :

```
// there is no need to return a bool
// if you need to return a value
// use any other return type other than boolean
public void Connect()
{
    if (!IsConnected)
    {
        //no need to intilize TcpClient, it's already initilized from the constroctur
        IsConnected = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Client [{0}] is now connected.", ID);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client [{0}] is already connected.", ID);
    }
}

// there is no need to return a bool
public void Disconnect()
{
    if (IsConnected && Tcp != null)
    {
        stream.Close();
        Tcp.Close();
        IsConnected = false;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nClient [{0}] is disconnected.", ID);
}
```

`IsConnected` property is covering the status. avoid redundancy.

```
public string Read()
{
    if (IsConnected)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[Tcp.ReceiveBufferSize];//create a byte array
        int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, Tcp.ReceiveBufferSize);//read count
        string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);//convert to string
        return str.TrimEnd(new char[] {'\r', '\n'});//remove CR and LF
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Client " + ID + " is not connected!");
    }
}
```

Validations and Exceptions always comes first, to make it readable, and clear to human eye, and also would give you a good understanding on what's coming next. So, Don't move them at the bottom of your code neither inside `else` clause. 
Instead do this :

```
public string Read()
{
    if (!IsConnected)
    {
        throw new Exception("Client " + ID + " is not connected!");
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[Tcp.ReceiveBufferSize];//create a byte array
    int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, Tcp.ReceiveBufferSize);//read count
    string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);//convert to string
    return str.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });//remove CR and LF
}
```

Lastly, disposable parts. You need to know when you call `Dispose()` or using `using` clause, the instance would be disposed, if there is a connection, it would be closed automatically, along with any inner disposable objects. At least, this would be mostly applied on .NET disposable objects.

also, if you want a better code readability, try to minimize the use of `return;` like on this line :

```
if (disposed)
return;
```

check this out :

```
#region dispose pattern

private bool disposed = false;

public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // Free any other managed objects here
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Dispose();
                stream = null;
            }

            if (Tcp != null && Tcp.Connected)
            {
                Tcp.Dispose();
                Tcp = null;
            }
        }

        disposed = true;
    }
}

~ClientClass()
{
    Dispose(false);
}

#endregion
```

Comment: Is it safe to use `NetworkStream` as a property? Or, should I rather keep it local?

Comment: @user366312 if you use `private readonly NetworkStream stream` this means, you only initialize it once by a constructor or inline assignment and it would be immutable.